# LINQ.Aggregate returning incorrect results

Tags: c#, string, linq, aggregate

I'm close, but not getting quite correct results. What I want is something like:

```
Market eq 'Seattle' or Market eq 'Denver'
```

etc. Here's some sample code:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("Seattle");
list.Add("Portland");
list.Add("San Francisco");
list.Add("Denver");
list.Add("Boston");

string field = "Market";

string result = list.Aggregate((i,j) => $"{field} eq '{i}' or {field} eq '{j}'");
```

This is what I'm getting from this code:

```
Market eq 'Market eq 'Market eq 'Market eq 'Seattle' or Market eq 'Portland'' or Market eq 'San Francisco'' or Market eq 'Denver'' or Market eq 'Boston'
```

Comment: Aggregate does not calculates the sum: `i` is the "old" value if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to write it as an aggragate, you can use:

```
list.Select(i => $"{field} eq '{i}'").Aggregate((i,j) => $"{i} or {j}");
```

Since `i` is here the result you obtained in the previous step. The problem is thus that we will here append strings every time, making this an *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* algorithm (with *n* the length of the result).

But this is quite inefficient. What you probably want is to use:

```
string.Join(" or ", list.Select(i => $"{field} eq '{i}'"));
```

This is (probably) more efficient, but it is - in my opinion - also more readable: it explains almost literally what you want to do.

Both generate:

```
csharp> list.Select(i => $"{field} eq '{i}'").Aggregate((i,j) => $"{i} or {j}");
"Market eq 'Seattle' or Market eq 'Portland' or Market eq 'San Francisco' or Market eq 'Denver' or Market eq 'Boston'"
csharp> string.Join(" or ", list.Select(i => $"{field} eq '{i}'"));
"Market eq 'Seattle' or Market eq 'Portland' or Market eq 'San Francisco' or Market eq 'Denver' or Market eq 'Boston'"
```

Comment: You can use `Aggregate` with `StringBuilder` as initial value and append all results to it. Which will keep algorithm in O(n)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Your tweak to my attempt produces incorrect results (although you did teach me more about how Aggregate() works!). It gives: Boston or Market eq 'Denver or Market eq 'San Francisco or Market eq 'Portland or Market eq 'Seattle''''. There are a few things wrong with it. However, I do like your recommended code and will use that. Thanks!

Comment: @birdus: yes, that is fixed now. I realized it when I ran it through the interactive shell :s

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Great! Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Fabio: a problem is that in that case we will need to handle the fact that the seperator should not be added *n* times, but *n-1* times.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, true - added possbile solution with `Aggregate` as an answer.

Comment: @Fabio: and +1 for that solution :).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `StringBuilder` for efficient string concatenating in case you have big amount of items.
And can continue using `Aggregate` in O(n) way too

```
const string SEPARATOR = " or ";
var query = list.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(),
                           (builder, item) =>
                           {
                               builder.Append(field);
                               builder.Append(" eq ");
                               builder.Append(item);
                               builder.Append(SEPARATOR);
                               return builder;
                           },
                           builder =>
                           {
                               builder.Length -= SEPARATOR.Length;
                               return builder.ToString();
                           });
```